# Run OpenVPN client in background

Tags: openvpn

I’m trying to start a VPN connection through a shell script but I can’t run it in background, I’ve tried with:

```
sudo openvpn --config "/home/user/config.ovpn" &
sudo openvpn --config "/home/user/config.ovpn" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Also try through a screen but I don’t know how to indicate the sudo password to run the openvpn command.

My idea is to make it work in the background as the bash script I’m creating must run some tasks connected to a particular vpn.

Any suggestions?

Regards.

Comment: If you trying to start and stop openvpn as a regular user that approach is not going to work. Take a look here https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/UnprivilegedUser for the solution. By the way, you're missing a ' &' at the end of the last command and you have an extra space in '> /dev/null' it should be '>/dev/null' and you probably would want 'nohup' before openvpn, but these changes won't make it work; I am just stating them so you know the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the file without a quotes and the `&` trailing ex.

```
sudo openvpn --config /home/user/config.ovpn &
```

This works for me.

The terminal will wait for an intro or the next command. Finally, you can disconnect with the `sudo killall openvpn` command.

Answer (score -1):

You may start openvpn in the "screen"

```
sudo -- sh -c 'screen -dmS OpenVPN openvpn --config /path/to/config.ovpn'
```

It's possible to stop OpenVPN with 1st closing the "screen":

```
sudo -- sh -c 'screen -S OpenVPN -X quit'
```

And 2nd kill the openvpn job:

```
sudo -- sh -c 'pkill -f "openvpn --config /path/to/config.ovpn"'
```